# For each $k$, $0 \leq a_k$. Suppose $\sum{a_k}$ diverges and $\lim _{k \to \infty}{ka_k}$ exists, then $\sum{\frac{a_k}{1+ka_k}}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of reals such that for
> each $k$, $0 \leq a_k$. 
>  Suppose $\sum{a_k}$ diverges and $\lim _{k \to \infty}{ka_k}$
> exists (to either infinity, or a real value), then $\sum{\frac{a_k}{1+ka_k}}$ diverges.

I'm not sure how I can interpret the behavior of $\sum{\frac{a_k}{1+ka_k}}$ and how it relates to the original series. I would like if someone could help me to make this observation, thanks

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2672194/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%7B%5Cfrac%7Ba_k%7D%7B1%2Bka_k%7D%7D%24)

Comment: Try to write $\frac{a_k}{1+ka_k} = \frac{1}{k}\cdot \frac{ka_k}{1+ka_k}$.